# Nodered - No data from smartmeter

Tags: docker-compose, raspberry-pi, node-red, smartmeter

I am running noderd on a raspberry pi 4 as docker container (as well as mosquitto, timescaledb and grafana). But I fail to get data from a smartmeter (sml protocol) into nodered. The raspi is connected to an optical sensor via usb cable and I get data on the raspi (sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | od -tx1).

I do not find any parameter configuration for the smartmeter node (node-red-contrib-smartmeter) to get any data into nodered. Below you see the flow (connection details: 9600 Baud rate, 8N1 - should be fine since it is from the manual and already worked before).

To check the serial device connection with the docker container I have installed serialport in nodered. After some adjustments the serialport node in nodered could connect to /dev/ttyUSB0. Now, I get values - strang ones - from my serial device into nodered.

But for the smartmeter node I still get no values even though the parameters are the same than from the serialport node. Do you have any idea? Is there an alternative for the smartmeter node that should work?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: strange values from a serial device sounds like wrong baud rate

Comment: That would be really strange, since the baud rate is in the manual of the smartmeter and with the same baud rate it has been already working for more than one year - but without node-red.